# I want my form layout to look exactly the same as the example( picture attached)

Tags: html, css

I want my form layout to look like the picture below:
[image: Example]

This is what I currently have:

```css
  label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 28%;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 2em;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  }
```

```html
<label for="First_Name"> First Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="First_Name">
<label for="Last_Name"> Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="Last_Name">
```

This is my output:
[image: My Output]

Comment: Please learn HTML and CSS then

Comment: _We can't help you without the required information!!!!_ On a more serious note, please check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @domsson i am still learning thats why i am asking.                                            I want my label to be on top and input field at the bottom just like in the picture but it must be next to each other.Btw if you want clarity you ask questions my friend :)

Comment: Learning is great, @lcarolus20 - but to get help, you should also learn how to ask a good question. :) Did you check the link? It lists all the important info that should be in your question. We're particularly missing (a) your code, (b) your current result/output and (c) an exact description of what doesn't work (as expected). All we currently have is what the output is supposed to look like.

Comment: Can this post/ queston please be reopen,because i have edited the question.I dont how to be more clear with regards to this question..Thank you

Comment: One way it can be improved is to also include the HTML required to create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (as is described in the link I pointed you to above). There is an editor button that allows you to create a [_stack snippet_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that will enable us to run your code right from the question. Give that a try. I currently can't vote to reopen questions (~100 rep missing), but hopefully someone else will once you've improved it. :)

Comment: @lcarolus20 try this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/ you can find many inbuilt design before starting with bootstrap have a look at some basics of `HTML` and `CSS`.

Comment: Thanks for adding your markup. The post was reopened. For next time, please turn your HTML and CSS into a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), as I had mentioned earlier. This time, I've done it for you. Assuming your issue is to position the `label`s above the `input`s, I've tossed up an answer for you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is one possibility:

- wrap each pair of `label` and `input` in a `div` (or similar)
- use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to get them to stack vertically

Everything else seems to be just a matter of inspecting the reference regarding the used colors and sizes, which you can do by using your Browser's Inspector (or looking at the source code). Alternatively, bring the provided image into an image editing program and check the colors there.

Here is a rough approximation based on the approach outlined above:

```css
body {
    background-color: #f6f7f5;
}
fieldset {
    display: flex;           /* use flexbox for content */
    justify-content: center; /* center items horizontally */
    border: none;            /* remove default fieldset border */
}
.input {
    flex-grow: 1;            /* take up free space within parent */
    flex-basis: 50%;         /* width (before growing/shrinking) */
    display: flex;           /* use flexbox for content */
    flex-direction: column;  /* arrange content vertically */
    margin: 1rem;
}
label {
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #5b5b60;
}
input {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    color: #9d9d9d;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px #eee;
}
.required label::after {
    content: "*";
}
.required input {
    border: 1px solid #a94442;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <div class="input required">
        <label for="First_Name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="First_Name">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <label for="Last_Name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Last_Name">
    <div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  padding: 4px
}

.overflow {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.pull-left {
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  float: left;
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <label for="First_Name"> First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="First_Name">
  </div>
  <div class="pull-left">
    <label for="Last_Name"> Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="Last_Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please turn your HTML/CSS into a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), so we can see the results right here in your answer.

Comment: i have updated. but you have to update by font size and border color. Thats it.